# Branch folding example unclear

Tags: cpu-architecture

I was learning about branch folding from a book called "Computer Organization" by Carl Hamacher (5<sup>th</sup> edition) when I came across this example:
[image]

Aditional details:

- Queue length here denotes the number of instructions present in the instruction queue
- F,D,E and W denotes the fetch, decode, execute and write stages of a pipeline respectively
- The dotted lines at instructions 2,3 and 4 (I<sub>2</sub>,I<sub>3</sub> and I<sub>4</sub>) denote that the stage the instruction currently is in is idle (i.e. waiting for the next stage to complete)
- I<sub>5</sub> is a branch instruction with branch target I<sub>k</sub>
- The pipeline starts with an instruction fetch unit which is connected to an instruction queue, which is connected to a decode/dispatch unit, which is connected to an execution unit and finally it ends with a write stage. There exists intermediate buffers between the decode, execute and write stages.

  My doubt here is how D<sub>3</sub> and D<sub>5</sub> of I<sub>3</sub> and I<sub>5</sub> are being performed in the same clock cycle in spite of the fact that there is only one decode unit (given) ? Further more, the instruction queue should be of length 2 at cycle 4, why is it still 1 ? As both F<sub>3</sub> and F<sub>4</sub> seem to be in the instruction queue and none of them have been dispatched at cycle 4.

Comment: What would make more sense is queueing them after decode, so D3 and D4 could happen *before* D5.  Unless you have branch prediction, or pre-decode as part of the fetch stage, you don't even know about a branch until you decode it.  Or maybe that's not the point of this example.  There is a fetch bubble from the branch, and the queue somewhere is hiding that bubble

Comment: ... hiding that bubble with execution stall cycles so you don't pay both penalties.  But yeah, IDK how it's decoding 2 instructions at once unless it has a separate branch-decode capability.  That's plausible.  Does the text of the book say more?

Comment: @PeterCordes On thorough reading, the text does mentions this - "many processors employ sophisticated fetch units that can fetch units before they are needed and put them in a queue" and "To be effective, the fetch unit must have sufficient decoding and processing capability to recognise and execute branch instructions". I've added screenshots of the explanation [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J8fTlkutP4MoJS21ISdFvOqB5Ip6la34), if that could help.